# MVC Devexpress, why textbox is always under label?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I want a label and a text box next to each other but i didn't do what i want. How can i do that?

```
ViewContext.Writer.Write(
       "<div class=\"edit_form\">" +
          "<div class=\"line\">"
    );

    Html.DevExpress().Label(label =>
    {
        label.Text = "Action";
        label.ControlStyle.CssClass = "label";
        label.AssociatedControlName = "Action";
    }).Render();

    Html.DevExpress().TextBox(textBox =>
    {
        textBox.Name = "Action";
        textBox.Width = Unit.Percentage(30);
        textBox.ControlStyle.CssClass = "editor";
    }).Bind(DataBinder.Eval(test, "Action")).Render();

    ViewContext.Writer.Write(
          "</div>"+
       "</div>"
   );
```

Comment: css: dispaly inline block

Comment: You might be also interested in the FormLayout component: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument16028

Comment: @CSharper inline block is not working when i add is required attribute :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DevExpress create every time a  element in the DOM, therefore sometimes couldn't be straightforward to customize the page. Anyway you can:

1) Use ASPxThemeBuilder to modify your DevExpress theme;

2) CSS:

```
<div style="float: left;"> Html.DevExpress().TextBox.. </div>
<div style="float: left;"> Html.DevExpress().TextBox.. </div>
<div style="float: left;"> Html.DevExpress().TextBox.. </div>
```